# Execute Procedure with Parameters in Sql Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having a procedure with two parameters and a table with two columns defined as `para1` and `para2`.

Now, there are around 5000 rows in a table and I want to run the procedure with using the columns values are input parameters.

I can run the procedure with static parameters but don't know how to do it using parameters in table.

Comment: Please, provide the DDL for the table and for the Procedure (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you are specific when asking you will obtain good responses.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options - looping or using dynamic T-SQL statement.

Here is example using the latter:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Param01] INT
   ,[Param02] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Param01], [Param02])
VALUES (1, 'a2')
      ,(2, 'a2')
      ,(3, 'a4')
      ,(4, 'a0');

DECLARE @DynamictTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT @DynamictTSQLStatement = 
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT CHAR(10) + 'EXEC [dbo].[my_stored_procedured] @Param01 = ' + CAST([Param01] AS VARCHAR(12))  + ', @Param02 = "' + [Param02] + '";'
        FROM @DataSource
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1
  ,1
  ,''
);


EXEC sp_executesql @DynamictTSQLStatement;
```

For a loop, the things are pretty the same as in all language. Read a row, get current parameters values, execute the routine and continue with the next row until all of the are read.

Answer (score 0):

I used below codes and it works

```
create procedure [procedurename] 
as
declare @field1 varchar(15)
declare @field2 varchar(15)
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
select field1, field2 from donor_update_list a
open cur
fetch next from cur into @field1, @field2
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
--execute your sproc on each row
exec uspYourSproc @field1, @field2
fetch next from cur into @field1, @field2
END

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Answer (score -1):

just create your procedure like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_proc_name @p1 nvarchar(30) = NULL, @p2 nvarchar(60) = NULL
AS
--your code
```

after that you can for example create a string by doing a query on your table like:

```
select 's_proc_name ', columnP1, ' ', columnP2
from tableName
```

This will return an output with you possible input.

after that you can execute the lines you want manually just copy pasting or you can put this in a temp table like:

```
select 's_proc_name ', columnP1, ' ', columnP2
into #tmp
from tableName
```

and execute programmatically each line just by using a loop on the table and execute the output string with `EXEC(@record)`